# Can't find component /atg/dynamo/servlet/adminpipeline/AdminHandler

Tags: jboss, atg, atg-dynamo

I hope someone will be able to help because i am struggling with this issue for two weeks now, and still not been able to find a solution.

I have got JBoss AP server installed on my Red Hat Linux machine. I am trying to trigger a build and deploy my application after the new changes in code i have made. During the deployment process, right after the server is stopped, and started again, i get the following error and the build/deployment just fails:

```
ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase] Servlet.service() for servlet     
AdminProxyServlet threw exception javax.servlet.ServletException: Can't find component: /atg/dynamo/servlet/adminpipeline/AdminHandler
    at atg.nucleus.servlet.NucleusProxyServlet.initServlet(NucleusProxyServlet.java:172)
    at atg.nucleus.servlet.NucleusProxyServlet.service(NucleusProxyServlet.java:212)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:173)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:182)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:241)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I have gone through ATG Installation documentation several times, have tried what is suggested there but doesn't work. 
During the search i found that the AdminHandler component that is been missing, is a component that is inluded when installing ATG platform.

I never had this kind of problem before, but one day two weeks ago, this started appearing.

Any thoughts?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

For this first you need to check that do you have /DAFEAR/Admin folder. 
If this is not exist then you need to install the ATG Dynamo. And if exist then re-compile your module with DafEar.Admin module.

```
runAssembler <yourmodule.ear> –m yourmodule DafEar.Admin
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try fresh ATG installation? And follow precisely ATG Installation Guide, after that I hope your problems will gone.